# How to modify Androidx Preference data outside of PreferenceFragment?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I am trying to implement a custom Radio-style `Preference` where the user can click an option which is then assigned as the new value of the `Preference`:

[image]

Here is my layout:

preferences.xml

```
<Preference
    android:layout="@layout/preference_gender"
    android:key="seeking"
    android:title="Seeking"/>
```

preference_gender.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/gender_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        ...
        android:text="@string/seeking"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/male"
        android:text="Male"
        />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/female"
        android:text="Female"
        />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/both"
        android:text="Both"
        />

</RadioGroup>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Because `Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener` can't detect specific clicks inside the `Preference` (only the preference as a whole), I've resorted to adding an `onClick()` function in the xml which is then passed to my activity:

then to my preferences fragment:

```
class PreferencesFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), View.OnClickListener, RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
    }


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    gender_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this) // null pointer exception
}


}
```

however I get a `NullPointerException` on my `findPreference("seeking")!!`.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

`preference_gender.xml` has no `Preference` keys at all. A styled `RadioGroup` & 3 `RadioButton` might rather be suitable to represent those buttons below a single `Preference` key; nodes alike that `AppCompatTextView` might be rendered - but won't be treated alike a `Preference` would be.

Comment: Thanks I've just changed the textviews to `RadioButtons` inside a `RadioGroup` and they can successfully be individually clicked. However a similar problem still remains: my `PreferencesFragment` can't detect the id of the `RadioGroup` in the layout file - there's a NullPointerException when I set the `gender_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this)` - any idea? I've updated my code.

Comment: @Zorgan that `preference_gender.xml` isn't a `PreferenceScreen` nor a `PreferenceGroup`... one cannot use the same XML markup there - and the `RadioGroup` requires a textual key, not a numerical id - so that it could be found and associated with a key & value.